# Update Firestore document map from several users

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to update a map in a document looking simplified like this:

```
Map{
    [
        key: timestamp + PlayerId (concatenated)
        value: actionId, playerId, timestamp e.t.c
    ],

    e.t.c.
}
```

What might happen rarely is that me and another users using this document wants to add an event to the map in close intervals.

What happens is that I successfully inputs the event but the other will loose its event.

The problem is that the other person have to update its document with the map before adding the new map. But using multiple users it gets deleted.

Is there a way to solve this? (Was not able to find information about this)

I can't create new documents instead of this since then it will be 100+ documents for the events which will be expensive.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to make sure that one update does not overwrite the other in a way that's not desirable.

Comment: Thank you very much for fast answer! Reading about it, definitely what I need!